# iOS - Crash in SFMCNetworkRequest with sdk v6.4.2

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-ios, push-notification

Stacktrace for the issue related to SFMCNetworkRequest using sdk v6.4.2

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Task created in a session that has been invalidated'

```
[ADEumNSURLSessionWrapper dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:] + 160
[SFMCNetworkRequest dataTask] (SFMCNetworkRequest.m:181)  
[SFMCNetworkRequest performRequestWithCompletionHandler:requestCompletionHandler:] (SFMCNetworkRequest.m:240)  
[MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence sendETAnalytics] (MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m:640)
[MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence applicationDidEnterBackgroundNotificationReceived]_block_invoke.344 (MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m:485)   
[SFMCTimedDispatcher dispatchWithIdentifier:onQueue:afterTimeInterval:completion:]_block_invoke (SFMCTimedDispatcher.m:59)
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved in the 7.x releases of the SDK.  Please update to the latest release, [v7.1.1 as of 20200519](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/).

Comment: Updating to latest SDK v7.2.1 didn't fix the issue. Still seeing good number of crashes with the same stacktrace as above. Is there any other suggestion to fix it?